Uniform bound for coefficients of fundamental forms of unbounded surface
Recently I am using the Gauss-Weingarten relations to transform an equation defined on a domain $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^3$ into a form expressed in local coordinates when it approaches the boundary $\Omega$. This leads to the appearance of coefficients of the second fundamental form and Christoffel symbols in the equation. For some purpose I need to obtain the uniform boundedness of these coefficients.
Assuming $\Omega$ is a $C^4$ bounded domain, then these coefficients can be imagined to be bounded (actually I don't know how to prove it). Now I want to consider the unbounded domain. Are these coefficients still bounded, or under what assumptions are they valid?

What is the analog of the statement you want for plane curves? Surely, the curvature of an unbounded (that is, not contained in a compact set) curve need not be uniformly bounded. Why expect this for surfaces?

The problem arises from my desire to generalize the results of an article on the Fokker-Planck equations on bounded domains (Hwang-Jang-Jung, SIAM, 2018, http://www.siam.org/journals/sima/50-2/M110992.html) to unbounded domains.

There, the coefficients are required to be bounded during the analysis

I could actually make these bounded properties an assumption, but I don't know if that's reasonable. Wouldn't these assumptions cause the surface to degenerate into a trivial plane?

I realized that I no longer understand what you are asking. What coefficients? In any case I would work out some simple example, e.g. when the boundary is rotationally symmetric.
